# Bytes avro type not deserializing with kafka confluent GenericAvroDeserializer

Tags: java, deserialization, avro, spring-kafka

I'm using `io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroDeserializer` to deserialize Kafka `Message<Bytes>` with
kafka "`value.deserializer`" configured as `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.BytesDeserializer` but the `GenericAvroDeserializer`
not deserializing the avro payload with below type

```
{
      "name": "totalAmount",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "logicalType": "decimal",
          "precision": 13,
          "scale": 2,
          "type": "bytes"
        }
      ]
    }
```

The resulted deserialized payload for attribute "`amount`" as below

```
"amount": {"bytes": "\u0001C"}
```

I see the internal implementation of AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer as

```
if (schema.getType().equals(Type.BYTES)) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
    buffer.get(bytes, 0, length);
    result = bytes;
}
```

is there any way to properly deserialize the payload using `io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroDeserializer`
with avro type as bytes

Answer (score 0):

I managed to deserialize this kind of bytes to decimal using this way:

```
LogicalTypes.Decimal decimalType = LogicalTypes.decimal(precision, scale);
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new Conversion.DecimalConversion().fromBytes((ByteBuffer) decimalInBytes, schema, decimalType);
```

This decimalInBytes is actually from GenericRecord when we do .get("totalAmount") from the instance of GenericRecord of your payload.